# Shift lock icon is appearing over show/hide icon in my password field?

Tags: ios

I have a password field in my app, that has show/hide button in password field.
This field is covered by `uppercase` icon when I tap shift 2 times at iPhone's keyboard (Caps Lock). This is not very nice and I wonder how to make it not showing? It's probably showing because my field is using `Secure Text Entry` property

[image]